# Mystery Activity Does Not Conform to App Theme

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, themes

after months of developing on the Android platform, I still have an unanswered question. I noticed a long time ago that I have ONE single Activity that doesn't conform to the rest of the app theme. This means that by default, the font color of the Activity is white (not black), and Checkboxes don't show up when not checked, you can't see them at all. Very peculiar behavior. Recently, I changed the colorAccent attribute of my theme, which changed ALL accent colors to orange (including Checkboxes), but this Activity remains unchanged. Has anybody ever experienced this?

I made this Activity into a fragment once, and it then magically conformed to the theme. After switching back to the Activity, even making a brand new Activity to host the logic, nothing has changed. Here's the Activity layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <me.core.utility.TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:id="@+id/title_bar"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Edit"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_editing_button"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_logout"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DONE"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/done_editing_button"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_logout"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's an image of what this all looks like:

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas why this Activity has gone rogue??

**EDIT**: Added Manifest

```
<application
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_trans2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".utility.AppInit"
        >

        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="software.gcm" />

                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".gcm.GcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->


        <!-- [START instanceID_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".gcm.InstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceID_listener] -->


        <!-- [START registration_service] -->
        <service
            android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
        <!-- [END registration_service] -->


        <!-- [START application activities] -->
        <activity
            android:name=".userinterface.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".session.InitSessionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".userinterface.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".userinterface.MainActivity"
             >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="me.core.userinterface.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".userinterface.AddBuddyActivity"
            android:label="Add Buddy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".userinterface.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".userinterface.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".userinterface.ModifyActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".userinterface.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".userinterface.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".userinterface.BuddyRequestsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".userinterface.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".userinterface.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".userinterface.ThreadDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_messages"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".userinterface.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".userinterface.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- [END application activities] -->
    </application>
```

**EDIT**: Added source

```
public class ModifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DeleteConfirmationDialog.DeleteConfirmationListener {
    private static String LOG_TAG = ModifyActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private BusProvider busProvider;

    /** UI references*/
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    TextView title;

    private Obj selectedObj; // The obj to be edited
    private ModifyActivityListAdapter modifyActivityListAdapter;

    private ArrayList<Buddy> buddiesToAdd; // Buddies to be added
    private ArrayList<Buddy> buddiesToRemove; // Buddies to be removed

    // Allows these two processes to keep track of one another, and go back to buddies activity when both are done
    private boolean additionDone;
    private boolean deletionDone;
    private boolean actionTaken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify);
        busProvider = BusProvider.getInstance();
        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
        int id = Integer.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra(ConstantValues.IntentArguments.ARG_ID));
        // The object to be edited
        selectedObj = databaseHelper.selectObjWithId(id);
//        if (selectedObj!=null) {
//            title.setText(selectedObj.getName());
//        }

        // Get all members of chosen obj
        ArrayList<Member> membersOfSelectedObj = databaseHelper.selectMembersOfObj(id);

        //Instantiate
        ListView editListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.edit_listview);
        // Create adapter
        modifyActivityListAdapter = new ModifyActivityListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), membersOfSelectedObj);
        // Attach adapter
        editListView.setAdapter(modifyActivityListAdapter);

        Button doneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done_editing_button);
        Button cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_editing_button);
        ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        ImageButton renameButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.rename_button);

        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                analyzeUserInput(modifyActivityListAdapter.getAllBuddies());
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createDeleteConfirmDialog();
            }
        });
        renameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createRenameConfirmDialog();
            }
        });

    }
```

**EDIT**: posting code of the list item, which is the thing that's really discolored. The checkbox should be orange, and font black, but they show up totally invisible (white), so I need to change the text color manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    tools:context=".userinterface.ModifyActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="howdy"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/edit_list_item_textview"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowColor="@color/lb_orange"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/edit_list_item_checkbox"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How have you declared this `Activity` in your `manifest` file, means declared with `android:theme` attribute ?

Comment: Yes, it's declared and the Manifest theme is already set.

Comment: Can you add your `Manifest` ?

Comment: Added, the activity in issue is ModifyActivity

Comment: Can you add the Activity's source code? The theme can be changed programmatically, so might be worth a shot checking there.

Comment: I posted the onCreateView code, which really is the only thing that touches the activity directly..

Comment: your relative layout has white color defined in xml? are you aware of that?

Comment: You mean as the background? Yeah, I'm aware. Shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @MsYvette yes that's what i mean

Comment: Nothing custom on this one @MsYvette

Comment: 16 and up.. All activities work fine except this one.

Comment: add your style code in question

Comment: can you post your adapter code

Comment: What is `@style/AppTheme`? Are all activities AppCompat activities?

Comment: In your xml, the `AppBarLayout` has a theme attribute. Can you try removing that.? Kinda feel somehow that's overriding your activity theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of how you construct your `ModifyActivityListAdapter`. You are giving it an *application context*, which the adapter uses to inflate its item views. Try passing in the activity context instead.

```
// Create adapter
modifyActivityListAdapter = new ModifyActivityListAdapter(this, membersOfSelectedObj);
```

By default, an application context does not hold theme information. As such, views inflated with it will not have your customized theme.

When you specify `android:theme` in your manifest's `<application>` element, it is not applied on the Application object, but rather at the activity level. The attribute is just for the convenience of specifying one theme that should be applied to all `<activity>` elements. You can use `Context.setTheme(..)` to apply a theme to your application context object, but that is not recommended. Instead, you should use an activity context whenever you work with views.

For more check out [Dave Smith's detailed article about the Context class](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/). It's from 2013, but Contexts didn't really change much since then.

Comment: All my Activities extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: Ok. Is there a reason that you are providing your ModifyActivityListAdapter constructor with an application context rather than an activity context?

Comment: no. It should be Activity Context. You're right! You think that would make a difference though? I need to learn more about when to use which one, but it is my understanding that you should only use App Context if whatever you're passing it to is relating to the entire application, and Activity otherwise...

Comment: Nicely spotted Jozua. I think you are probably right.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jozua. That was an awesome catch, and I never thought that using the Application's context vs an Activity's could cause so much havoc. The problem is now fixed, and I awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

On the xml layout file that is being used on setContentView go to the visual design portion and look at the top header in that window. You can set your theme by clicking the button to the left of the activity name tab.

Answer (score -1):

have you checked if its a issue in code, like you might have an issue with view holder design pattern in your listview implementation. As the adapter code has not been posted

Comment: This has happened to be me before, but isn't the case in this instance. No custom background is being set or anything modifying the list item view...